# getting xml response instead of json in .net while deserialising it

Tags: c#, php, json, codeigniter, deserialization

I am Writing a PHP Codeigniter code for a callback and I was supposed to get a json response but when my partners are supposed to call this callback API are working on .net (C#) when they are deserialising it they are getting XML response but where ever I try like the browser or postman I am getting JSON only. how can this happen

**MY PHP CODEIGNITER CODE**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
         $Txntype = $_GET['Txntype'];
         $Timestamp = $_GET['Timestamp'];
         $Bcid = $_GET['BcId'];
         $Terminalid = $_GET['TerminalId'];
         $transactionID = $_GET['TransactionId'];
         $Amount = $_GET['Amount'];
         $txnStatus = $_GET['TxnStatus'];
         $BankIIN = $_GET['BankIIN'];
         $TxnMedium = $_GET['TxnMedium'];
         $EndCustMobile = $_GET['EndCustMobile'];
         $usertransactionId = mt_rand(111111,999999);
         $outletdetail = " match bc id in table" ;
         $userid = '123';
         if($outletdetail != '')  
         $MESSAGE = "Success";
         $array1 = array('STATUS'=>'SUCCESS','VENDOR_ID'=>12345,'TRANSACTION_ID'=>$usertransactionId,'MESSAGE'=>$MESSAGE);             
         }else{
         $MESSAGE = "Failure";
         $array1 = array('STATUS'=>'FAILED','VENDOR_ID'=>$transactionID,'TRANSACTION_ID'=>$usertransactionId,'MESSAGE'=>$MESSAGE);
         $table1='kp_aeps_checkstatus';
         $data=$this->Finacial_model->magagram_aeps_checkstatus_insert_data($array1,$table1);

         }
         return $this->response($array1);

         }
```

**MY JSON RESPONSE**
while testing in postman or broswer

```
{
    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
    "VENDOR_ID": 12345,
    "TRANSACTION_ID": 611966,
    "MESSAGE": "Success"
}
```

But when they are deserialising in .net(C#) they are getting the response like this[RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxtmy.png)
is there any error from my side because everyone code is working but when I am sending it's not working I tried to use another person code whose code deserialised successfully but I am unable to get it

Comment: Check what value for the `Accept` request header they are sending. This sounds like some sort of automatism in the background, that automatically adapts the output format based on what the client has requested resp. indicated as preferred format(s).